# CSS responsives, close menu automatically

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to CSS, I am working on the responsive for a page.
I have a menu bar on the left side of the screen, which can be retracted on a click on a button, I want to make it so that once the screen size reaches a certain size, the menu will retract automatically without user having to click on the button.

```
<a href="#" class="menu-toggle icon" id="left-menu-toggle" title="Menu">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</a>
```

this is the menu button.

Comment: I do actually want to hide the button as well, so user cant open or close the menu and make the screen go crazy

Answer (score 2):

You could just hide the menu using a media query and display none.

You can adjust the max-width based on the size of the device you want the menu to hide on. Currently the styles will be applied for all devices with a size of 480px or smaller.

Something like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #left-menu-toggle {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Additionally you could also use `min-width:481px` and have the menu be a `display:block` on larger screens. This is know as mobile first because you're targeting your css towards mobile devices and then changing things for larger devices.

Comment: No problem. Do let us know if it works. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
  @media screen and (min-width: 780px) {
  fa-bars {
    display: none;
  }
}
```